# Android Studio totally can't find new resource folders

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I correctly added the "newfolder", using select Project, then new Resource Directory under res, choosing mipmap type folder etc.

[image]

No matter what I do, the new files (example "teste") will NOT APPEAR as a drawable in Project.

(New pngs I drop in to "mipmap-xxhdpi" work perfectly ... notice "hamburger" etc. appears fine.)

i HAVE rebuilt, cleaned, invalidated-caches-restart.

Absolutely no difference.

What's the deal?

This on a Mac, latest everything. (I'll try the project on a PC and report.)

Comment: Please note that the `mipmap` folder/s should only contain the **application launcher icon**, not the other graphical resources. For those ones, you're encouraged to use the standard `drawable` folder/s. I.e.: `drawable-xxhdpi`, in this case

Comment: Thanks for that....

Comment: You're welcome, Joe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I correctly added the "newfolder"

By definition, that is incorrect. You cannot invent new resource types, like `newfolder`.

> No matter what I do, the new files (example "teste") will NOT APPEAR as a drawable in Project.

That is because it is not a drawable. If you want to create a drawable resource, put it in a `drawable` resource directory. For example, perhaps instead of `newfolder-xxhdpi`, you might create `drawable-xxhdpi`.

Comment: Thanks. So; consider the four items in mipmap-xxhdpi.  In fact, there is *no way* to just put 2 in one folder and 2 in another. (For convenience.) All four must be in mipmap-xxhdpi?

Comment: @JoeBlow: Assuming that all four represent `-xxhdpi` resources, then yes, they all have to be in `mimap-xxhdpi/`. A resource directory is based off of a resource type (`layout`, `mipmap`, `drawable`, `menu`, etc.) and a series of suffixes describing the rules for when to apply that particular directory's resources (e.g., `-w820dp` for "use when the current screen width is 820dp or wider"). You cannot invent new resource types. You are stuck using naming schemes (e.g., prefixes) to help organize resources within a directory, or using completely separate library modules.